# Preferred way to implement @OneToMany lazy fetch of child

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA and creating a sample app using Hibernate with Spring. From various posts and Google I found few approaches to implement the LAZY fetch.

- One most discussed approach seems [open session in view pattern](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView), though many raised various disadvantages of this approach.
- Another approach is the use of Join Query (ex. `select p from Partner p join fetch p.contacts where...`).

Please explain the preferred way of implementation that I may choose.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The good way is the second way.

Open session in view pattern is sort of anti-pattern practice. It gives chances to change entities in JSP/Servlet level. It's not safety to data and is a bad programming practice.

The perfered way is to manually load the lazily-loading fields of an entity before using it or use ***fetch*** reserved word in HQL statement. what/which data you will use in view layer is the thing you should know in advance by yourself, so the duty to prepare/load data before use them is yours, it's common sense thing.

Here are some ways to load lazily-loading fields in advance:

1. Set fetch mode to get field value eagerly when querying

   Criteria.setFetchMode(String associationPath, FetchMode mode);
2. *Hibernate.initialize()* method to initialize proxy field.
3. add ***fetch*** in HQL statement.

   select emp from Employee as emp fetch join on emp.dept as dept where dept.name like 'HR'